# Finding list item from javascript generated html

Tags: c#, javascript, html

Here is all the code I am using for this multiselect box which I found at [multiselect page](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/)

HTML:

```
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="ui.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.localisation-min.js"></script>
<script src="ui.multiselect.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".multiselect").multiselect();
    });
</script>

<form runat="server">
    <select class="multiselect" multiple="true" style="width:460px; height:200px;">
        <option value="AA">AA@gmail.com</option>
        <option value="AB">AB@gmail.com</option>
        <option value="AC">AC@gmail.com</option>
        <option value="AD">AD@gmail.com</option>
        <option value="AE">AE@gmail.com</option>
        <option value="AF">AF@gmail.com</option>
   </select>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

C#:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] emailList = new String[1000];
    //find the ul in the html and loop through each li
}
```

What this all translates into on the client side is this (I'm not sure all of this is 100% correct as I did just copy and paste if from the browser, however all of the relevant information is here):

```
<div class="ui-multiselect ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget" style="width: 514px;">
    <div class="selected" style="width: 272px;">
        <div class="actions ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
            <ul class="selected connected-list ui-sortable" id="multiselectedItems" runat="server" style="height: 164px;">ev
                <li class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" style=""/>
                <li class="ui-state-default ui-element ui-draggable" title="AA@gmail.com" style="display: list-item;">ev
                <li class="ui-state-default ui-element ui-draggable" title="AB@gmail.com" style="display: list-item;">ev
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="available" style="width: 234px;">
</div>
```

Now for the question, I need to find and loop through each of those list items in the unordered list, get the title attribute and store it in a string array when the button is clicked. I have already tried to find the control using Form.Request["multiselect"] and Page.FindControl["mutliselect"] but non of those worked. As always any help is welcome, thanks.

EDIT #1:
I looked and searched but there apparantly isn't a way to do this, however, instead of creating a new almost identical question, I'll just edit this one... Is there a way to modify the javascript file from the multiselect box I linked above? I thought if it is possible then it might be easier to just let the javascript add an attribute to the  control within the select... I'm just not sure where in the javascript I can add this, so heres the updated question... Where in this multiselect javascript file must I edit in order to make it add an attribute to the correctly selected option?

Comment: In javascript or C#??

Comment: I need to find it using C#

Answer (score 0):

you can do giving runat="server" and id tags to your html select element

```
   <select runat="server" Id="SelectList" class="multiselect" multiple="true" style="width:460px; height:200px;">
            <option value="AA">AA@gmail.com</option>
            <option value="AB">AB@gmail.com</option>
            <option value="AC">AC@gmail.com</option>
            <option value="AD">AD@gmail.com</option>
            <option value="AE">AE@gmail.com</option>
            <option value="AF">AF@gmail.com</option>
       </select>


    ***


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect)SelectList.SelectedIndices.. 
    String[] emailList = new String[1000];
    //find the ul in the html and loop through each li
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately... it will return all of the emails, not just the selected emails. It looks as tho the javascript only edits the generated code and not this HtmlSelect control.

Answer (score 0):

One way, certainly not the most elegant, is to use the HtmlAgiliyPack to scrape your code for the `<li>` elements and extract the title

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
//Path to the file on the filesystem
doc.LoadHtml("patch to your htmlfile");

if (!doc.DocumentNode == null)
{
   foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='email']"))
   {
       //add title to your array
       //I recommend using a List<string> instead
       //list.Add(node.innerHtml);
   }

}
```

If you want to load resources from the web you need to use a slightly different code:

```
var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("http://www.path.com/to/your/file.html");
foreach(var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='email']"))
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Yes totally, check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659019/Scraping-HTML-DOM-elements-using-HtmlAgilityPack-H for a quick tutorial on how it works.

Comment: What should I type in for the "path to your htmlFile"? is that the physical file on the server?

Comment: Yes it is. I have updated my answer with an alternative way if you want to load a file from the web.